# How to archive a pool?

Tags: pool, toloka

I want to archive an old pool in Toloka, which I no longer need. I have created new ones to label new batches and the old ones are just interrupting my work I can't find a button.

Answer (score 1):

In Toloka, there is a restriction on archiving pools with unreviewed or rejected tasks. This is because you can't change the task status in archived pools, like review a submitted response or accept a previously rejected task. You can't archive a pool that contains tasks rejected less than 9 days ago.

https://yandex.com/support/toloka-requester/concepts/pool-archive.html